# Как сделать слово ( поток?) ожидающее завершения других потоков?

Tags: многопоточность, forth

Как сделать слово (поток?) ожидающее завершения других потоков?

Answer (score 2):

Для ожидания завершения потока следует ожидать на хэндле этого потока.

```
REQUIRE Wait      ~pinka/lib/multi/Synchr.f
REQUIRE LAUNCHED  ~pinka/lib/multi/launch.f

: t 2000 PAUSE ;
: test
  ['] t LAUNCHED ( -- h ) >R
  ." waiting for t ... "
  R@ -1 Wait IF ." finished" ELSE ." failed" THEN
  R> CLOSE-FILE THROW
;
```

Comment: REQUIRE LAUNCHED  ~pinka/lib/multi/launch.f нет этого в

Comment: Обновитесь из [репозитория](http://spf.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/spf/): скачайте и распакуйте [tarball](http://spf.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/spf/?view=tar). Т.к. там юниксовые переводы строк, то пропишите в начало spf4.ini команду `UNIX-LINES`.